# "As possible" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

> It has had pernicious, copycat consequences: just last week, China
> adopted the same approach in sanctioning British lawyers and
> parliamentarians merely for investigating **as possible genocide** the
> mistreatment of the Uyghurs,” he said.

I think that **as possible genocide** here means a treatment which can possibly amount to a genocide.

I couldn't find a similar example in dictionaries. Is this phrase a common one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is what it means. The mistreatment is known, but whether it amounts to genocide is being investigated.

The phrase (without the 'genocide') is quite common:

*"...investigating as possible murder the sudden deaths of three dissidents."*

*"...investigating as possible theft the disappearance of the statue."*

The crimes - genocide, murder, theft - are singular but the phrase is also commonly used with plurals:

*"...interviewing as possible candidates the three French diplomats."*